# MediaWiki Vector skin and load.php error in Chrome and others browsers

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome, mediawiki, mime-types, mime

```
MediaWiki 1.24.2
PHP 5.4.39 (cgi-fcgi)
MySQL 5.5.42-cll
```

Hi, I installed a new clean Wiki 1.24.2 in my VPS host, and now I have a problem with skins and load.php in Google Chrome.

I tried all of solutions I find on this board and other sites, like some code in .htaccess (this fix the problem in Firefox) and LocalSettings minimal changes and stuff (cache, localhost URL, etc.).

But in Google Chrome, Opera and other similar browsers -included mobile version- nothing work.

The specific error is:

> Refused to execute script from
>   '/w/load.php?debug=false&lang=es&modules=jquery%2Cmediawiki&only=scripts&skin=vector&version=20150521T163633Z' because its MIME type ('(null)') is not executable, and strict MIME
>   type checking is enabled.

and...

> index.php?title=Especial:Entrar:14 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet
>   but transferred with MIME type text/plain:
>   "/w/load.php?debug=false&lang=es&modules=mediawiki.leg….button%2Ccheckbox%2Cinput%7Cskins.vector.styles&only=styles&skin=vector&*".

Error screenshot: imgur[.]com/1jJiUDs.png

So, all the CSS and Vector skin is gone.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?w/images/thumb/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2 [L,QSA,B]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?w/images/thumb/archive/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2&archived=1 [L,QSA,B]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} only=styles
RewriteRule ^load.php - [QSA,E=content_type:text/css]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} only=scripts
RewriteRule ^load.php - [QSA,E=content_type:application/javascript]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(redirect|load|texvc|index).php
RewriteRule ^(api|load)\.php - [L]
```

.htaccess screenshot: imgur[.]com/fGtfCoF.png

This is my htaccess, this fix (I guess) the problem only in Firefox and sometimes I can see everything perfectly in other browsers until -after a couple of clicks- error happen again. I think it's an important, check it as soon as possible because affects the entirety wiki and cause inconvenience to visitors.

My wiki: pediars[.]com

Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: I don't see any problem using firefox.

Comment: I'm surprised that you have to add all that stuff to `.htaccess`: was it broken before? Did you alter `$wgMimeType`? MediaWiki is supposed to set the content-type by itself. Also, what is `^load.php` supposed to match if the path is `/w/load.php`?